# Использование dll

Tags: c++builder, dll

Кто может подсказать, как в консольном приложении открыть dll, в которой находятся некоторые методы.

Comment: открыть dll всегда можно через fopen:)
или нужно просто использовать функции, которые есть в длл? Тогда через LoadLibrary, как обычно.

Comment: Библиотека программы StreamingMediaPlayer - UMediaControl.dll, в ней есть методы для управения, нужно открыть библиотеку и выполнить консольно подключение и проверку работает ли соодинение, не выдавая сообщений в виде MSGBOX, а если нет, то сигнал наподобие \a.

Comment: .h или .lib файл к UMediaControl.dll есть?

Comment: Нет, но builder открывает ее и можно увидеть все методы, разработчики описывают использовать ее через Activex, но не представляю, как в с++ это сделать.

Comment: стоп. это обычный activeX?
Импортировали в билдер? так кто мешает в include прописать и создавать как обычный объект.

Comment: Если его включить в include, то при обращении ругается и он открывается в бинарном виде.

Comment: http://umediaserver.net/bin/UMediaSDK.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Visual C++ это делается так:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (__cdecl *CALLABLE)();

int main(void) 
{ 
    if (HINSTANCE instance = LoadLibrary(TEXT("SomeDLL.dll"))) 
    { 
        if (CALLABLE callable = (CALLABLE)GetProcAddress(instance, "SomeFunc")) 
            (callable)();

        FreeLibrary(instance); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Думаю, что в Borland C++ похоже.

Comment: а можно комментарии к коду?