# Работа с DLL, способы вызова функций

Tags: c, dll

У меня очень "новичковый" вопрос (никогда в жизни не работал с DLL) и состоит он в следующем:
У меня есть 3 файла f1.c f2.c f3.c. В каждом из них вот по таким функциям:

```
// f1.c
int f1()
{
    return 2;
}

// f2.c
int f2()
{
    return 4;
}

// f3.c
int f3()
{
    return 10;
}
```

потом я получил три отдельных объектных файла, с помощью команды (использую mingw по windows):

```
gcc -c f1.c f2.c f3.c
```

и далее я создаю DDL-ку, командой:

```
gcc f1.o f2.o f3.o -o test1.dll -shared
```

получился файл test1.dll

С помощью DLL Export Viewer я открыл и посмотрел свой DLL файл:
[image]

Как я теперь могу динамически или статически (вот это я еще плохо понял) обращаться к этой библиотеки, для вызова функций f1(), f2() ( а если бы в функции были бы параметры входные? ) например из своего C++ приложения? Что я вообще могу делать с этим файлом?

Извиняюсь за немного глупый вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Использование dll](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26869/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-dll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Случайно удалил свой ответ, что смог восстановил. Давно уже не работал, там все очень просто, разбираться не сложно, примерно так:

1. если динамически, загружаете dll, получаете ссылку на функцию по имени (напр. "f1"), используете функцию по ссылке;
2. если статически, подключаете библиотеку к проекту, объявляете внешнюю функцию и сразу можно вызывать в программе.

В обоих случаях надо знать прототип функции. Более подробно см.:

- http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?22
- http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?41

Надо еще разобраться с методами вызова функций:  http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Соглашение_вызова

Comment: как это делать достаточно хорошо описано во втором примере http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?41  
в Windows например, API функции хранятся в dll, в стандартных заголовочных файлах они обявлены и готовы для использования, надо лишь статично подключить к проекту, а некоторые/основные по умолчанию уже добавлены (это в VC++).

Comment: не открывается у меня DLL, когда этот код использую :( :
HINSTANCE hModule=NULL;
 hModule=::LoadLibrary("user32.dll");
 if (hModule!=NULL)
 {
  ::FreeLibrary(hModule); 
 }
 else cout << "error load Dll" << endl;

Comment: dll не загружается, если этот файл dll отсутствует либо не верно указан путь, возможно, файл dll имеет неверный формат

Comment: Для статической компоновки, насколько я помню, нужен LIB-файл, который получается в процессе сборки DLL. И при его подключении не нужно думать о том загружена DLL или нет - все происходит автоматически.

Comment: это я дурак... забыл его добавить в проект в VS

Answer (score 2):

Все сводится к вызовам LoadLibrary, FreeLibrary и GetProcAddress. Посмотрите здесь на пример: [использование dll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26869/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-dll?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#26917).