# Добавление библиотек

Tags: c++

Как добавить библиотеку в код программы (если библиотека не содержится в компиляторе)?

Мне нужно в программу вставить команды из библиотеки Serial Gate, а для этого нужно сначала включить эту библиотеку, а вот как это сделать я не знаю(

Comment: Должен тебя разочаровать - в компиляторе нету библиотек =( делай по старинке - импорт

Comment: Какая среда? В MVStudio жмете alt+F7, находите место, где включаются библиотеки, и прописываете свою, и дел нет, так что уточните, что именно Вы подразумеваете под выражением "Как добавить библиотеку в код программы".

Comment: Где она лежит и как называется (имя файла) ? И еще, в таких вопросах пишите какая ОС и какой компилятор.

Comment: И какая библиотека. Или это библиотека объектных модулей или dll

Answer (score 3):

В C++ библиотеки состоят из заголовочных файлов (.h, .hh, .hpp), которые нужны компилятору (cl в Win, gcc в Linux), чтобы собрать из исходников объектные файлы, и бинарного модуля (статический или динамически подгружаемый: .lib, .dll в Windows, .a, .so в Линукс), с которым объектные файлы линкуется с помощью линкера (link в Windows, ld в Linux), превращаясь в исполнимый файл или библиотеку.

"Добавить библиотеку в код программы" в переводе на язык C++ означает объявить в исходниках программы ссылку на заголовочные файлы библиотеки ("заинклюдить").

```
#include <mylib/mylib.h>
```

После этого программа скомпилируется в объектные файлы, но не слинкуется, линкер скажет, что в объектном файле неизвестные символы. Линкеру нужно указать путь к бинарным модулям библиотеки. Тогда линковка произойдёт и из объектных файлов на свет появится исполнимый файл (либо библиотека, смотря что компилируете).

Компилятор и линкер настраиваются по-разному в зависимости от платформы.

Если что-то непонятно - спрашивайте, постараюсь ответить.

Comment: С терминами аккуратней пожалуйста. Поскольку "бинарные модули" в юниксоподобных системах в первую очередь -- выполняемые файлы в двоичных кодах (native или псевдокод -- java, mono, чёрт с рогами), а относить туда объектники... (Правда немало форматов, которые могут используоваться и для загрузки, и для линковки -- тот же elf, например)

Comment: @alexlz Не-не, бинарным модулем я назвал не объектник, а .so или .a (.lib, .dll). Edit: "в бинарном модуле неизвестные символы" - да, тут ошибся, сейчас исправлю...

Answer (score 0):

Если это Windows, и библиотека динамически подгружается (DLL), то доступ к функциям получается стандартным методом LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, FreeLibrary. Подробнее здесь: [использование DLL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26869/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-dll/26917). Если библиотека подключается статически (LIB), то надо просто прописать нужные пути для сборщика и добавить необходимые заголовки.

Answer (score 0):

Может что-то такое нужно: [импорт вызовов функций с помощью __declspec(dllimport)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zw3za17w.aspx)?

Answer (score -1):

`man ld` - инструкция к линкеру (именно он связывает вызовы функций в программе с библиотеками) и компонует исполняемый модуль.

Если вопрос более конкретный, то опишите **конкретную** проблему.