# Подключение библиотек в С++

Tags: c++

Хочу использовать библиотеку tinyxml, скачал ее, но не знаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы компилятор ее увидел..
Работаю в Windows, в Far-е

Comment: Нужно прочитать документацию на используемые средства разработки: Visual Studio, mingw или что там у вас. Еще можно посмотреть сопроводительную документацию к самой библиотеке, там может быть написано как ее подключать в различные проекты.

Comment: @Anton: Far — это нортонообразный менеджер файлов. Прекрасная замена Проводнику, кстати, для олдскульных программистов.

Comment: @VladD, та ладно Вам :D far активно использую.. Изначально в вопросе в слове `Far-е` дефиса не было;) думал может имелось в виду какая-то тайная IDE: "`Fare`"

Comment: @Anton: А, вот оно что! Я не видел оригинал вопроса. :-)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/43186/181472

Answer (score 2):

TinyXml — это маленькая, header-only-библиотека.

Поэтому просто положите её (tinyxml.h и возможно tinystr.h) в отдельный каталог и подключайте через `#include`.

Ваши средства разработки (Visual Studio или там MinGW) в данном случае не при чём, т. к. в библиотеке нету скомпилированного кода.

---

Уточнение: как правильно заметил @zenden2k, библиотека на самом деле *не* header-only. Согласно [документации](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/):

> It is two headers and four cpp files. Simply add these to your project and off you go.

то есть

> Она [библиотека] состоит из двух header-файлов и четырёх cpp-файлов. Просто подключите их к вашему проекту и всё.

То есть вам нужно рядом с header'ами положить и cpp-файлы и добавить их наряду с остальными исходниками в ваш проект (Visual Studio) или makefile.

Comment: "header-only-библиотека"
неправда

Comment: @zenden2k: Принято, уточнил ответ.

Comment: И в который раз, люди, очевидно не разбирающиеся в предмете,  закрыли вопрос.